# Pointer or class as iterator?

Tags: c++, containers

I'm writing a random access container in C++. In my code I use this (well, in my real code I use all kinds of Allocator typedefs, this is just easier to understand):

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class Carray {
public:
    // ...
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    // ...
};
```

But I can also create a different iterator class derived from `std::iterator`. This would add support for typedefs (`it::iterator_category`, `it::difference_type`, etc).

Now my question, is there an overhead by using a iterator class instead of a raw pointer? If yes, how substantial is this overhead, and is it severe enough to not use a iterator class?

Comment: A class with only inline members probably has no overhead at all (varies by compiler).  But with the introduction of `iterator_traits`, there's no need to have the typedefs inside the iterator class at all.

Comment: The most important question here, why are you creating your own `std::vector`?

Comment: Xeo: I'm not creating my own `std::vector`, for educational purposes I'm creating a fully working and fully standardized C-style array: a dynamically sized (but not re-sizable) array that supports the general c++ container magic but also implicitly converts to a pointer to the first element (so it can be passed smoothly to C functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have iterator category, difference type etc avalaibale for you even if you have a raw pointer. You see, there is this `iterator_traits<>` template which you should use. It is already specialized for pointers.

```
iterator_traits<int*>::value_type // ... etc. 
//or
iterator traits<my_custom_iterator>::value_type
```

Comment: Alright, so given my iterator `it` I can define the according `iterator_traits` specialization, if necessary. I must assume that people use `iterator_traits` if they want info about my iterator, but I'll take that for granted (I'll put it in the documentation).

Comment: @nightcracker: If your iterator is a poiner, you needn't do anything spectial. For T* value type is T, pointer type is T* etc. It is automagically done for you. If it is a custom iterator with nested typedefs as value_type, etc, then you shouldn't do anything either, because iterator_traits<It>::value_type is defined as typename It::value_type automatically, if It is not a pointer

Comment: Yes, I know (that's what I meant with the "if necessary"). I'm still going to define it, just to be sure, because my class uses `typedef typename Allocator::difference_type difference_type;` and such.

Comment: @nightcracker: Yes, if you need custom  behavior, you specialize iterator_traits

Answer (score 2):

If your iterator class simply wraps the pointer, there is almost certainly no overhead.

It's perfectly standard-conforming to use raw pointers as the iterators. However, some badly written code (including, as you suggest, code that tries to use nested typedefs directly instead of iterator_traits) may fail to compile. Some of the early standard libraries started with pointers for vector's iterators and changed, purely to keep such bad code working. That's really the only reason I'd think of for bothering.

BTW - if possible I'd make use of the Boost iterator support rather than deriving directly from std::iterator; a lot of subtle requirements are taken care of for you that way.